# pandas conditionally fill values with 0 and 1

Tags: python, pandas

Doing the following conditional fill in pyspark how would I do this in pandas

```
colIsAcceptable = when(col("var") < 0.9, 1).otherwise(0)
```

Comment: np.where() may be helpful here. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-where-in-python/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
df['new_col'] = df['col'].lt(0.9).astype(int)
```

or with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['col'].lt(0.9), 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).

```
import numpy as np
df['colIsAcceptable'] = np.where(df['col'] < 0.9, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colIsAcceptable = df['var'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x < 0.9 else 0)
```

apply can be slow on very large datasets, and there are more efficient ways that I don't know of, but is good for general purposes

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['col2'] = 0
df.loc[df['col1'] < 0.9, 'col2'] = 1
```

This is a simple example to do something like what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the first column on your dataframe is named 'var'. and then the second column name is 'colIsAcceptable', then you can use `.map()` function

```py
df['colIsAcceptable']= df['var'].map(lambda x: 1 if x<0.9 else 0)
```